# No mylib.so under libs

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an app with ndk lib. I can build it successfully ,but afterwards I can't see my `lib.so` under `prj->libs->armeabi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, you have to refresh every time you build (click on the project in Project Explorer, then F5 or right-click->Refresh). If you can't find it in the directory either, try building with `ndk-build -B`. This will force it to rebuild everything.